# File attachment on .NET Core/Razor application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

How do I add a file attachment using .NET Core/Razor on my application to be able to read/download uploaded files? The Microsoft documentation on stream reader only gives me how to upload/delete the files, but not how to link it on html to be able to download/save/open the file.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad.  What have you tried that isn't working?  There are a number of ways to go about saving the file and then serving it up for people to download/save.  As an example you could store the file content in a database, you could store it in a cloud storage service like S3, etc.

Comment: I'm storing the files on my local SQL server database and need a way to add a link for users in my application to be able to download/save/open the file attachment. Most examples I found uses a directory which is something I don't want. I need a StreamReader of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're storing the data in a database.  It sounds like you might want to leverage the `FileContentResult` class for this.  You can give it a `byte[]` and a content type to serve up the file to your users.